# Simply install any Brother's printer drivers

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

Your system is up to date, you try system-config-printer to set up your Brother printer but you don't find your model it in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **demonipuch** from [ubuntu.fr forum](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=652931). Open a terminal (somewhere like your user's folder) and follow instructions. This is quick and simple.

Download script:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/demonipuch/brprinter-installer/get/master.zip
```

Extract:

```
unzip master.zip
```

go to folder:

```
cd demonipuch-brprinter-installer-*
```

launch script:

```
sudo bash brprinter-installer
```

When it says: "Entrez votre modèle", tip your model, Ex with DCP-J752DW:

```
Entrez votre modèle : DCP-J752DW
```

Then choose between 0=usb install (recommended) or 1=network (NOT recommended).
So type 0:

```
Sélectionner le type de connectivité : [0] USB [1] Réseau
Entrez le choix : 0
```

Enjoy to check your install in system-config-printer!
This script download and install the drivers from brother's site.
Tested from 12.04 to 20.04, should work for any ubuntu version.

**To add network printer**, I recommended to:

1. Go to system-config-printer
2. Duplicate usb printer or create a new one.
3. Use search tools to find your network printer. (if not, something is bad)
4. Then you will be enable to select your model in the driver list proposed in "brother".

Answer (score 0):

Tried this to get a Brother MFC-J6930DW printer to work in Ubuntu 22.10 but it didn't work. I had found a similar sounding driver installer on the Brother web page but with no instructions how to use it. The combination of the Brother installer and these instructions on use, worked and the printer is back in service after updating from 22.4. This installer uses English rather than the French.

Thank you. Jim